# Flickr API call IIFE

Tags: javascript, flickr

Using an IIFE always gives me a 'callback-function-name' is not defined error. A regular load function on the other hand works fine. Any ideas appreciated guys...!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  (function() {

    function myfeed(feed) {
      alert(feed);
    }

    var tags = 'potatoes';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=myfeed&tags=' + tags;
    document.head.appendChild(script);


  }());

</script>
```

Comment: Any ideas on what? Your `myfeed` function is scoped so it's not globally available.

Comment: You should perform AJAX call.

Comment: the function is not written correctly, change last line to `})();`

Comment: @self nothing wrong with the way he wrote the function. `}())` is also correct. The way you're suggesting simply allows the passing in of a parameter. It's irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`jsoncallback=myfeed` is going to look for a global function. Currently, `myfeed` is scoped inside of the IIFE.

If you want to make it globally available, you need to do something like this:

```
function myfeed(feed) {
  alert(feed);
}

(function() {

  var tags = 'potatoes';
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=myfeed&tags=' + tags;
  document.head.appendChild(script);

}());
```

Comment: So does the jsoncallback NEED to be a global function ?

Comment: It doesn't NEED to be global. But with this IIFE structure, it needs to persist in a scope independent of the IIFE.